# Windows 10 Map network drive not possible

Tags: windows-10, vpn, network-shares

I'm not getting why I can no longer map a network drive which is readily available if I go through the file explorer and simply type in \server\share.

It worked fine i.e. I had the location mapped but all of a sudden it just won't work anymore unless I go through the file explorer.

I should include that I connect to the drive using VPN (Sonic wall net extender)

Any idea as to why this is a problem all of a sudden?